# How to perform like operation in hiberante 5

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, java-8, jpql

How to perform the following query in hibernate 5?

```
select * form product where name like "%s%" or sku like "%s%"
```

I am using the following code so far but it's not working.

```
searchText = "%" + searchText + "%";
// Search the text.
try {
    // Get the record with the username.
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ProductsEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ProductsEntity.class);
    Root<ProductsEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(ProductsEntity.class);

    Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[2];
    predicates[0] = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(ProductsEntity_.name), searchText);
    predicates[1] = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(ProductsEntity_.sku), searchText);
    criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.or(predicates));
    Query<ProductsEntity> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<ProductsEntity> productsEntityList = query.getResultList();

    productsEntityObservableList.setAll(productsEntityList);

    // Set the product table view to the observable list.
    tvProductsList.getItems().clear();
    tvProductsList.getItems().addAll(productsEntityObservableList);
    } catch (HibernateException e ){
                WindowsUtility.displayAlert("Database Error", "Unable to connect to database", Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Following error occurs:

> Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module
>   'RestrauntManagementSystem' Information:javac 1.8.0_201 was used to
>   compile java sources Information:3/14/19 10:51 PM - Compilation
>   completed with 2 errors and 4 warnings in 2 s 254 ms Warning:java:
>   source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>   Warning:java: target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a
>   future release Warning:java: To suppress warnings about obsolete
>   options, use -Xlint:-options.
>   /home/kazekage/IdeaProjects/RestrauntManagementSystem/src/main/java/admin/ProductsController.java
>   Warning:(258, 27) java: isNumber(java.lang.String) in
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils has been deprecated
>   Error:(288, 63) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable
>   ProductsEntity_   location: class admin.ProductsController Error:(289,
>   63) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable ProductsEntity_
>   location: class admin.ProductsController

Comment: Are you writing jpql or using criteria? What have you tried so far?

Comment: To learn how to perform a query with LIKE in hibernate 5, do a web search for [`hibernate 5 like`](https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+5+like). This is known as **research**, and you apparently need to learn how to do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`like` is a valid keyword in both jpql and hql, so you can easily use it in `@Query` or in any other way. Example:

```
@Query("select e from Entity e where e.someField like :param")
public Entity getEntityBySomeField(@Param("param") String param);
```